# Visual Studio 2013 Setup project - How to disable the Cancel button in small progress bar dialog?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, setup-project

I have one windows form UI wizard as custom action in MSI setup project in Visual Studio 2013. During installation one small progress bar dialog appears on top of the UI. This dialog also has a Cancel button and text like 'Please wait while Windows configures....'

Can we hide or disable this dialog somehow? Can we disable the Cancel button on this dialog? Or can we take this dialog behind the main UI so that user will not be able to click Cancel? Or Can we detect this Cancel button click event and handle in custom action?

Comment: I am able to get rid of this Progress Bar dialog DURING INSTALLATION by adding one of the canned UI dialog like Welcome or Finished. Though this added dialog is redundant but installation is not showing the Progress Bar.

The problem still exists for Un-installation. I wanted to use the same approach for Uninstallation as well but it does not allow me to add a canned UI dialog for uninstallation. 

After going through some links and posts about this problem I am looking for some work around like detecting the Cancel button Click during Un-installation and handle this in my custom Action?

Answer (score 0):

There's no good answer to this, so basically this is just information.

The Windows Installer architecture expects all UI to be done in the first UI sequence, that's where data is entered. You probably understand this from the vast majority of other setups that do this. The execute sequence is intended to be silent except for errors and a progress bar. When Visual Studio setups allowed installer classes as a way for people to run managed code custom actions I don't think they expexcted people to have UI there. It often doesn't work because of the STA/MTA thread differences for message pumps, and since Windows Installer itself knows nothing about your custom action showing UI (there's not supposed to be UI!) it still believes it has the user's focus. The other issue is that many customers expect to be able to do silent installs, your requirement for a UI wizard defeats this.

I think some people have tried to solve your problem by enumerating all the Windows on the system to find the Windows Installer one and forcing it to the background, but I haven't seen anything recently on this or any code examples.

In your case, if your UI data can be collected up front with one of the canned UI dialogs then try that. Unfortunately VS setups don't give you a way to validate the input. If the UI wizard is for the app itself then it's usually easier to do it when the app first runs, as well as being easier to test and debug, being able to run later to reconfigure, and avoiding this kind of issue.

The limitations of VS setups include not being to design your custom dialogs to collect and validate input in the expected way at the beginning UI sequence. Also you cannot disable the Cancel button because VS custom actions run after everything is installed, which is too late to send the message saying "disable the cancel button".  The overall issue is that you're fighting the limitations of VS setups, and another tool might be a better way to go, or have that UI wizard run at first boot of the app.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to hide the progress bar dialog itself using Win32 APIs.

Comment: Yes, it's not difficult, but VS custom actions all run at the end of the install when everything is installed, so it's not really a solution for VS setups.